# pygame not updating draw.rect with key presses, even though x and y values are being update

Tags: python, pygame

I'm fairly new to programming and I'm working on building Pong just a beginner project. I have written the following code to try to move the two paddles, but neither of them moves when the up/down/w/s keys are pressed. However, in trying to debug this myself, I set it up to print the x and y values to the console, to see if that was the issue, and the x and y values are updating, but the coordinates of my rectangles are not. I'm sure it is a fairly simple fix, but I'm quite new to programming and just don't know what's wrong. Here is my code:

```
import time
pygame.init()
screenW = 800
screenH = 600
win = pygame.display.set_mode((screenW, screenH))
pygame.display.set_caption("Pong")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 20)
paddleW = 20
paddleH = 100
ballSpeed = 15

class paddle(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.pad = (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,255,255), self.pad)

class ball(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, side):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.side = side
        self.pad = (self.x, self.y, self.side, self.side)

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,255,255), self.pad)

def redrawGameWindow():
    win.fill((0,0,0))
    paddleLeft.draw(win)
    paddleRight.draw(win)
    theBall.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()



#Main Loop:
paddleLeft = paddle(10, screenH//2, paddleW, paddleH)
paddleRight = paddle(screenW - 10 - paddleW, screenH//2, paddleW, paddleH)
theBall = ball(screenW//2, screenH//2, 30)
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(30)
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        print("left up")
        print(paddleRight.y)
        paddleRight.y -= ballSpeed

    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        print("left down")
        print(paddleRight.y)
        paddleRight.y += ballSpeed

    elif keys[pygame.K_w]:
        print("right up")
        print(paddleLeft.y)
        paddleLeft.y -= ballSpeed

    elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
        print("right down")
        print(paddleLeft.y)
        paddleLeft.y += ballSpeed

    redrawGameWindow()


pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the attributes `x` and `y`, the the content of the list `pad` doesn't change magically.

You have to update `.pad`, before drawing. For instance:

```py
class paddle(object):
    # [...]

    def draw(self, win):
        self.pad = (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,255,255), self.pad)
```

Anyway, I recommend to use a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object instead of the attributes `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`:

```py
class paddle(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,255,255), self.rect)

class ball(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, side):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, side, side)

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,255,255), self.rect)
```

---

Complete example:

```py
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()
screenW = 800
screenH = 600
win = pygame.display.set_mode((screenW, screenH))
pygame.display.set_caption("Pong")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 20)
paddleW = 20
paddleH = 100
ballSpeed = 15

class paddle(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,255,255), self.rect)

class ball(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, side):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, side, side)

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,255,255), self.rect)

def redrawGameWindow():
    win.fill((0,0,0))
    paddleLeft.draw(win)
    paddleRight.draw(win)
    theBall.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()


#Main Loop:
paddleLeft = paddle(10, screenH//2, paddleW, paddleH)
paddleRight = paddle(screenW - 10 - paddleW, screenH//2, paddleW, paddleH)
theBall = ball(screenW//2, screenH//2, 30)
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(30)
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        print("left up")
        print(paddleRight.rect.y)
        paddleRight.rect.y -= ballSpeed

    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        print("left down")
        print(paddleRight.rect.y)
        paddleRight.rect.y += ballSpeed

    elif keys[pygame.K_w]:
        print("right up")
        print(paddleLeft.rect.y)
        paddleLeft.rect.y -= ballSpeed

    elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
        print("right down")
        print(paddleLeft.rect.y)
        paddleLeft.rect.y += ballSpeed

    redrawGameWindow()


pygame.quit()
```